# Path issue when publishing my Shiny App on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, path

I have a big dataset that I am trying to import to R, so I could do some calculations and publish it on shinyapps.io but it looks like I have a problem with paths. I have tried many things advised on different websites but nothing helps.
First I had a code with setwd but then I have read that RShiny does not like set-up paths.
All my files used for this app are in one folder which is C:/Users/MK0008/OneDrive - GROUP/Reports/Aug 2021.

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/MK0008/OneDrive - GROUP/Reports/Aug 2021/report_rating.csv") 

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Competency"),
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           plotOutput("Competency.Name", click = "plot1_click")
    ),
    column(5,
           br(), br(), br(),
           htmlOutput("x_value"),
           verbatimTextOutput("selected_rows"))),
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df1 <- df
  df1$Competency.Self.Rating <- revalue(df$Competency.Self.Rating, c("Unrated"=100))
  df1[df1 == ""] <- NA     
  df1$Competency.Self.Rating[is.na(df1$Competency.Self.Rating)] <- 100
  
  df1$Competency.Official.Rating <- revalue(df$Competency.Official.Rating, c("Unrated"=100))
  
  report <- with(df1, table(Competency.Official.Rating, Competency.Name))
  report <- as.data.frame(report)
  
  report_stats <- report %>% 
    arrange(Competency.Name, desc(Competency.Official.Rating)) %>% 
    group_by(Competency.Name) %>% 
    mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Freq))
  
  x_val <- reactive({
    x <- req(input$plot1_click$x)
    lvls <- levels(report$Competency.Name)
    lvls[round(input$plot1_click$x)]
  })
  
  y_val <- reactive({
    x <- req(x_val())
    y <- req(input$plot1_click$y)
    report_stats %>% 
      filter(Competency.Name == x,
             y <= cumsum) %>% 
      slice(1L) %>% 
      pull(Competency.Official.Rating)
  })
  
  output$Competency.Name <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(report, aes(x = Competency.Name, y = Freq, 
                       fill = Competency.Official.Rating, label = Freq)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
      geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
  })
  
  # Print the name of the x value
  output$x_value <- renderText({
    HTML("You've selected <code>", req(x_val()), "</code>",
         "<br><br>Here are the first 10 rows that ",
         "match that category:")
    
  })
  
  # Print the rows of the data frame which match the x value
  output$selected_rows <- renderPrint({
    x <- req(x_val())
    y <- req(y_val())
    head(report[report$Competency.Name == x & report$Competency.Official.Rating == y, ], 10)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Logs

```
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415217+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415217+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:     summarize
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415458+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415460+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415729+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415730+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415730+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:30.416603+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Warning in file(file, "rt") :
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415459+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415729+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2021-09-15T14:45:30.415459+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:     filter, lag
2021-09-15T14:45:30.416636+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:   cannot open file 'C:/Users/MK0008/OneDrive - GROUP/Reports/Aug 2021/report_rating.csv': No such file or directory
2021-09-15T14:45:30.424287+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Error in value[[3L]](cond) : cannot open the connection
2021-09-15T14:45:30.424289+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2021-09-15T14:45:30.424290+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Execution halted
2021-09-15T14:45:42.769209+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Running on host: 96c37721974a
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773852+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Server version: 1.8.6.1
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773854+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773866+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: R version: 4.0.3
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773877+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: shiny version: 1.6.0
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773887+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: httpuv version: 1.6.2
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773905+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773935+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: knitr version: (none)
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773943+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773989+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2021-09-15T14:45:42.773990+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: htmltools version: 0.5.1.1
2021-09-15T14:45:42.774121+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
2021-09-15T14:45:42.954964+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2021-09-15T14:45:42.958185+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:42.958186+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Starting R with process ID: '42'
2021-09-15T14:45:43.367366+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:43.367368+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2021-09-15T14:45:43.367369+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368081+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368351+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368083+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368351+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368632+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368352+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:     filter, lag
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368083+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:     summarize
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368634+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:43.377283+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Execution halted
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368631+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2021-09-15T14:45:43.369523+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:   cannot open file 'C:/Users/MK0008/OneDrive - GROUP/Reports/Aug 2021/report_rating.csv': No such file or directory
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368352+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: 
2021-09-15T14:45:43.377280+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Error in value[[3L]](cond) : cannot open the connection
2021-09-15T14:45:43.377282+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368082+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:     arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
2021-09-15T14:45:43.369521+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]: Warning in file(file, "rt") :
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368634+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2021-09-15T14:45:43.368081+00:00 shinyapps[4658467]:
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You're specifying the path to the file on your computer. The file won't be on your computer when it is running on shinyapps.io

Comment: You should also load the file into R on your local computer and then save the life as a .Rdata file and upload the file when you push you app to shinyapps.io